# How to find the weight of heaviest edge in the path between two nodes in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The idea I have heard about is finding the Lowest Common ancestor (LCA) of these 2 nodes using the binary lifting method. To know more about it:

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/#Lowest%20Common%20Ancestor%20(LCA)

But I don't know where in that algorithm I can store the weight information. Any ideas??

Comment: If you have the path it is a simple Max issue - store temporarly the max value you've seen while traversing and replace it if you saw bigger value

Comment: Yes that could certainly work but its complexity is O(N) worst case and I may be asked that question more than N times, so I get out of bounds in time. Should have mentioned that in my question though sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a tree for LCA as follows. In the weighted input tree, find the heaviest edge, delete it, and construct two (output) trees recursively, one for each remaining component of the input. Make these output trees the children of a newly created root. (The base case is to turn a single vertex into a single vertex.)

Say we have an unrooted weighted tree:

```
    1     5     4
 A-----B-----C-----D
       |     |
       |2    |3
       |     |
       E     F
```

The rooted tree that we prepare for LCA is:

```
        5
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    2       4
   / \     / \
  1   E   D   3
 / \         / \
A   B       C   F
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate because I didn't completely understand your answer? Firstly, what do you mean output trees? Then I understand deleting heaviest edge and making subtrees, but how can I use that to find heaviest edge fast??

Comment: @ThemistoklisHaris You preprocess the tree into another tree, which you then feed to the LCA preprocessor.

Comment: Explanation of transformation of the tree is needed.